# How to use JPA Inheritance

Tags: jpa

I have two classes one is non entity class suppose A which is of having the common fields in all the entity classes and the other is an entity class which is extending the entity class.The way i am defining these classes as below.

```
public class A{
     private Date startDate;
     private Date endDate;
     //setters and getters for these fields
     }

@Entity
@Table(name="some table name")
public class B extends A{
     private long id;
     private String duration;
public B(){

    }
public B(Date startDate,Date endDate,String duration){
     //setter methods for the fields inside the constructor             
    }
    //Setter ,Getter methods for the fields in B class
   }
```

Now the problem is when i run the application it is creating the table with the fields defined in the B class only.The table is not having the fields in the super class(class A).Where i am doing wrong...

Answer (score 5):

Inheriting from non-entity class does non inherit persistent attributes. In JPA (2.0) specification this is told with following words:

> The non-entity superclass serves for inheritance of behavior only. The
>   state of a non-entity superclass is not persistent. Any state
>   inherited from non-entity superclasses is non-persistent in an
>   inheriting entity class.

If your goal is to inherit persistence mappings only, then using [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) will server your goals. Idea is that then only persistent mappings are inherited, and possibly reused in, to multiple entities extending same mapped superclass. From persistence point of view there is then no relationship between mapped superclass A and extending entity B, just reuse of persistence mappings. If your mappings are otherwise sound, only things that is needed is to add `@MappedSuperClass` annotation to class `A`.

If you want to use super class A in queries and relationships, then it should be entity (mapped superclass will not work). Good way to start is to read corresponding part from Java EE [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqn).

Comment: What is interesting is that if you use XML descriptors, you can target `private` fields in the (non-entity) superclass, thus "making" them JPA attributes.  EclipseLink 2.5.2 at least supports this behavior.  I am not sure the specification is as clear as it could be here.